# How can I connect to remote systems using PowerShell inside a Nano Server Docker container, specifically build 1809?

Tags: powershell, docker, dockerfile, powershell-remoting, nano-server

**Background**

I have a .NET application that I would like to install inside a Nano Server Docker container, specifically build 1809.  The app is basically a REST server which will receive a REST request and depending on the contents of the JSON, invoke a particular PowerShell cmdlet on a particular remote system and return the results in JSON format.

I was able to create a Nano Server Docker container with both PowerShell and .NET Core installed.  However, I ultimately realized that there is no WinRM installed on the container and therefore it is impossible to invoke remote PowerShell cmdlets.

My host system is Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.379).  I am using Docker Desktop for Windows (Version 2.0.0.3) with Windows containers enabled.

**Dockerfile**

Here is the Dockerfile I am using.  I created it by combining portions of the Dockerfile from [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docker/blob/master/release/stable/nanoserver1809/docker/Dockerfile) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/2.2/sdk/nanoserver-1809/amd64/Dockerfile).

```
# escape=`
# Args used by from statements must be defined here:
ARG fromTag=1809
ARG InstallerVersion=nanoserver
ARG InstallerRepo=mcr.microsoft.com/powershell
ARG NanoServerRepo=mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver

# Use server core as an installer container to extract PowerShell,
# As this is a multi-stage build, this stage will eventually be thrown away
FROM ${InstallerRepo}:$InstallerVersion  AS installer-env

# Arguments for installing PowerShell, must be defined in the container they are used
ARG PS_VERSION=6.2.0

ARG PS_PACKAGE_URL=https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v$PS_VERSION/PowerShell-$PS_VERSION-win-x64.zip

SHELL ["pwsh", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

ARG PS_PACKAGE_URL_BASE64

RUN Write-host "Verifying valid Version..."; `
    if (!($env:PS_VERSION -match '^\d+\.\d+\.\d+(-\w+(\.\d+)?)?$' )) { `
        throw ('PS_Version ({0}) must match the regex "^\d+\.\d+\.\d+(-\w+(\.\d+)?)?$"' -f $env:PS_VERSION) `
    } `
    $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; `
    if($env:PS_PACKAGE_URL_BASE64){ `
        Write-host "decoding: $env:PS_PACKAGE_URL_BASE64" ;`
        $url = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($env:PS_PACKAGE_URL_BASE64)) `
    } else { `
        Write-host "using url: $env:PS_PACKAGE_URL" ;`
        $url = $env:PS_PACKAGE_URL `
    } `
    Write-host "downloading: $url"; `
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; `
    New-Item -ItemType Directory /installer > $null ; `
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -outfile /installer/powershell.zip -verbose; `
    Expand-Archive /installer/powershell.zip -DestinationPath \PowerShell

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Retrieve .NET Core SDK
USER ContainerAdministrator
ENV DOTNET_SDK_VERSION 2.2.401

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile dotnet.zip https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/$Env:DOTNET_SDK_VERSION/dotnet-sdk-$Env:DOTNET_SDK_VERSION-win-x64.zip; `
    $dotnet_sha512 = 'ed83eb5606912cd78d7696fbdc8e8074afa95fda84eec57b078d7371848ad15fe91aaf521b85e77c69b844a7b036a2c0b7b6cac87a8e356643980d96b689af93'; `
    if ((Get-FileHash dotnet.zip -Algorithm sha512).Hash -ne $dotnet_sha512) { `
        Write-Host 'CHECKSUM VERIFICATION FAILED!'; `
        exit 1; `
    }; `
    `
    Expand-Archive dotnet.zip -DestinationPath dotnet; `
    Remove-Item -Force dotnet.zip
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Install PowerShell into NanoServer
FROM ${NanoServerRepo}:${fromTag}

# Copy PowerShell Core from the installer container
ENV ProgramFiles="C:\Program Files" `
    # set a fixed location for the Module analysis cache
    LOCALAPPDATA="C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local" `
    PSModuleAnalysisCachePath="$LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\docker\ModuleAnalysisCache" `
    # Persist %PSCORE% ENV variable for user convenience
    PSCORE="$ProgramFiles\PowerShell\pwsh.exe" `
    # Set the default windows path so we can use it
    WindowsPATH="C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows"

# Set the path
ENV PATH="$WindowsPATH;C:\Program Files\PowerShell;C:\Program Files\dotnet;"

COPY --from=installer-env ["\\PowerShell\\", "$ProgramFiles\\PowerShell"]

# intialize powershell module cache
RUN pwsh `
        -NoLogo `
        -NoProfile `
        -Command " `
          $stopTime = (get-date).AddMinutes(15); `
          $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' ; `
          $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; `
          while(!(Test-Path -Path $env:PSModuleAnalysisCachePath)) {  `
            Write-Host "'Waiting for $env:PSModuleAnalysisCachePath'" ; `
            if((get-date) -gt $stopTime) { throw 'timout expired'} `
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 6 ; `
          }"

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COPY --from=installer-env ["/dotnet", "/Program Files/dotnet"]

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

USER ContainerAdministrator
EXPOSE 80/tcp
EXPOSE 5985/tcp
EXPOSE 5986/tcp
EXPOSE 7777/tcp
EXPOSE 7778/tcp

CMD ["pwsh.exe"]
```

**Docker Commands**

Here are the Docker commands I am using to create and access the Docker container (note the directory contains a single Dockerfile with the contents above):

```
docker build C:\powershell-nanoserver1809-with-dotnet-2.2.401
docker create -t --name NanoServerHelloWorld -h NanoServer -i <ID_RETURNED_FROM_PREVIOUS_COMMAND>
docker start -i NanoServerHelloWorld
```

**PowerShell and WinRM commands that fail**

On other systems I can use the following PowerShell code to create a CimSession to a remote system and subsequently invoke a PowerShell cmdlet:

```
$u = "REMOTE_DOMAIN\REMOTE_USERNAME";
$pw = "REMOTE_PASSWORD";
$secStr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString;
$pw.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secStr.AppendChar($_)};
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $u, $secStr;

$Session = New-CimSession -ComputerName 172.27.0.114 -Authentication Negotiate -Credential $Cred -OperationTimeoutSec 900
```

But in this container I get this error message:

```
New-CimSession : FAILED
At line:1 char:12
+ $Session = New-CimSession -ComputerName 172.27.0.114 -Authentication  ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-CimSession], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimException,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.NewCimSessionCommand
```

Further, if I try to configure WinRM in anyway, I get the following (from cmd):

```
C:\>winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="*"}
'winrm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Also, if I look at services on the container, I don't see WinRM:

```
PS C:\> Get-Service

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  cexecsvc           Container Execution Agent
Running  CryptSvc           Cryptographic Services
Running  DcomLaunch         DCOM Server Process Launcher
Running  Dhcp               DHCP Client
Running  DiagTrack          Connected User Experiences and Teleme…
Running  Dnscache           DNS Client
Running  EventLog           Windows Event Log
Stopped  KeyIso             CNG Key Isolation
Stopped  LanmanServer       Server
Running  LanmanWorkstation  Workstation
Stopped  lmhosts            TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper
Stopped  mpssvc             Windows Defender Firewall
Stopped  Netlogon           Netlogon
Stopped  NetSetupSvc        Network Setup Service
Running  nsi                Network Store Interface Service
Stopped  Power              Power
Running  ProfSvc            User Profile Service
Running  RpcEptMapper       RPC Endpoint Mapper
Running  RpcSs              Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
Running  SamSs              Security Accounts Manager
Running  Schedule           Task Scheduler
Stopped  seclogon           Secondary Logon
Running  SystemEventsBroker System Events Broker
Running  TimeBrokerSvc      Time Broker
Get-Service : Service 'TrustedInstaller (TrustedInstaller)' cannot be queried due to the following error:
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Service
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotGetServiceInfo,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand

Stopped  TrustedInstaller   TrustedInstaller
Running  UserManager        User Manager
Stopped  VaultSvc           Credential Manager
Stopped  WerSvc             Windows Error Reporting Service
Stopped  WinHttpAutoProxyS… WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Serv…
Stopped  wisvc              Windows Insider Service
```

**Question**

Is there a way to get WinRM installed and working on a Nano Server Docker container build 1809?  If not, is there some workaround to connect to remote systems with PowerShell to invoke PowerShell cmdlets?

Perhaps there is some special Docker command I am missing, or some other Nano Server image available which has this missing feature?

Thanks very much in advance.